# Don't Repeat Yourself with commuting properties

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures, dry

Suppose I have a model class `Person` with a `name` property.

I also have a corresponding `PersonView` which contains a `NameView` as one of its subviews.

The `PersonView` also keeps a reference to a person (its model), and the `NameView` keeps a reference to the name (its model).

If I am inside the `PersonView`, I now have two ways to get at the name: either

```
self.person.name
```

or

```
self.nameView.name
```

All the references are natural.  Yet this would appear to be a violation of DRY.  The above paths are supposed to produce the same name.  But if something gets out of synch, they might not.

The above example is much simpler than these things tend to be in practice.  For example, the person might be part of a `Family` object, which in turn is referenced by a `FamilyView` object.  There are now three different paths from the `FamilyView` down to the name of a given person.  As the tree grows, it only gets worse.

What is the best way to handle the situation?

Answer (score 1):

I think that, in this situation, you have to choose between violating DRY or giving up loose coupling. I don't think you can avoid both.

If the `NameView` doesn't contain its own copy of the data, then it would need a pointer back to the data. Now you've tightened the coupling, because `NameView` can't be used just by itself.

On the other hand, if `NameView` keeps a duplicate of the model data then you are violating DRY and you can end up with synchronisation problems. Lots of GUI frameworks have a "binding" concept that keeps the values synchronised between the model and the view.

Personally, I'd pick loose coupling plus bindings. You shouldn't have any synchronisation issues if the bindings you use are any good. The wide spread use of bindings in lots of different languages and frameworks would suggest that this is a decent approach.

As for whether to use `self.person.name` or `self.nameView.name`, that depends on whether you're trying to modify model state, or view state. If you're trying to change the model, then just change `self.person.name`. The view should be observing the model somehow for changes, and should be able to update itself accordingly. If you want to update the GUI and you don't care about the model, then use `self.nameView.name`.

Comment: It would always be a pointer.  Alas, iOS doesn't have bindings; it does have key-value observing, which is somewhat close.

Comment: I'm a Cocoa developer mainly so I could have this wrong, but I think the idea in iOS is to do the synchronisation manually in the controller. If you really want bindings, they are fairly simple to implement on top of KVC and KVO. I'm sure you'll find someone who has already implemented it if you google around a bit.